# How can I avoid this error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python, selenium

```
while True:
    try:
        result = login(browser, url)
        if not result != 0:
            login(browser, url)
            while True:
                try:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    browser.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
                except:
                    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]").click()
```

It shows error on this line:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Restart Battle')]").click()
```

I tried removing parentheses and spaces and other stuff, but it isn't going off.

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

When using try, you need an except. For example, the following code prints `error`:

```py
try:
    x=1/0
except:
    print("error")
```

But this throws an `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`:

```py
try:
    x=1/0
# except:
#   print("error")
```

So, you need an exception at the end of the try statement here:

```
while True:
    try:
        result = login(browser, url)
        if not result != 0:
        ...
    except:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that in your script something *begins*, but the EOF (End of File — the file is your script) occurred *before it ends.*

(Similar as the unexpected “The End” in a watched crime thriller without revealing a perpetrator.)

It means that you started something (e.g. writing `"` as a start of the string literal), but you *never ended it* (no closing `"`).

The typical cases are unbalanced quotes, apostrophes, parentheses, and so on.

In your case it is the first `try:` without the expected `except:` just in the 2<sup>nd</sup> line of your script.